# How to stop chain in Spring Integration when error thrown?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm throwning one exception my Spring Integration chain but even though that exception, code continues to work. I'm expecting stopping of everything and don't continue.

But in my code it doesn't stop, the requestOutputChannel tries to work even though the exception. The errorHandlerChannel can't catch that exception and stop the flow.

What am I doing wrong?

Let me show with code:

This is my chain definition:

```
<int:chain input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="requestOutputChannel">
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:error-channel ref="errorHandlerChannel" />
    </int:header-enricher>

    <int:transformer id="transformer1" method="transform">
        <bean class="transform1Class" />
    </int:transformer>

    <int:transformer id="transformer2" method="transform" >
        <bean class="transform2Class" />
    </int:transformer>

    <int:transformer id="transformer3" ref="transform2Class" method="check"/>

</int:chain>
```

This my transform2Class transformer class

```
@Controller
public class CheckValidationmpl {
     public Message<?> checkValidation(Message<?> incomingMessage) throws Throwable {
           if(condition)
              throw new Exception("Demo!");
     }
}
```

This is the bridge to stop and return the code:

```
<int:bridge input-channel="errorHandlerChannel" output-channel="endFlowChannel" />
```

I expect, if there any exception thrown, the errorHandlerChannel must catch it and give to endFlowChannel, the requestOutputChannel musn't try to work.

Edit 1:
This is the operationGateway definition. The flow starts with this:

```
<int:gateway id="operationGateway"
             service-interface="com.paycore.core.integration.gateway.OperationGateway"
             default-request-channel = "requestChannel"
             default-reply-channel="endFlowChannel"
             default-request-timeout="40000"
             error-channel="errorHandlerChannel"/>
```

EDIT 2:

If there is an exception, the requestOutputChannel tries to worn even though the exception and it's definition like this. The wire-tab gives another exception because it doesn't have necessary informations because of the exception which thrown in CheckValidationmpl. There is something like bypasses my exception in CheckValidationmpl and continues to work instead of returning.

```
<int:channel id="requestOutputChannel">
    
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap id="demoWire" channel="demoEventChannel" selector-expression="!headers.containsKey('selectorKey')" />
    </int:interceptors>
    
</int:channel>
```

Comment: You need to show the complete flow (upstream from the chain's `requestChannel`).

Comment: @GaryRussell, I added operationGateway definition which starts the flow.

Comment: Turn on TRACE logging for `org.springframework.integration` category to see how your messages travel through the flow. The Message History is also useful to track the path of the message. Something indeed is off in your config, e.g. another subscriber to the same channel somewhere…